# Azure Pipelines fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/site/repo/': OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0 after a Pull or Push command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, bitbucket

I've been using CI/CD with Azure Pipelines and before the build and publish there's a simple Bash Task to update the Version number of our site and push that to git. This has been running OK until last week.

Now every time there is a `git pull` or `git push` command, the Pipeline fails and the logs return:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/site/repo': OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
```

A few things to mention:

- I am using OAuth to connect and I've allowed the OAuth to be persistent throughout the tasks:
  [image]
- We're using Bitbucket Cloud.
- the git commands work as expected when ran locally (tested on 2 different machines)

Here's the bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config http.timeout 600
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global http.sslVerify false

git config --list    

    set -e
    git checkout {branch name}
    git pull
    git status
    {code to edit a string in our .csproj file...}
    git add .
    git commit
    git tag -f dev_$todaysdate HEAD
    git status
    git push origin {branch name} dev_$todaysdate
```

git configs:

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/{path}
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=master
safe.directory=*
http.sslverify=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://bitbucket.org/{site}/{repo}
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
gc.auto=0
http.version=HTTP/1.1
http.https://bitbucket.org/{site}/{repo}.extraheader=AUTHORIZATION: basic ***
```

Any help, please?

Comment: What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted Agent or Microsoft-hosted Agent? If you are using self-hosted agent, you can check if there are Firewall or Proxy blocking the connection.

Comment: I'm using a "windows-2019" agent From Azure

Comment: Can you try to change to use Windows-2022 Agent and check if it has the same issue?

Comment: Just tried Windows-2022. Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you try to add the following git commands in your bash script: `git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy`  `git config --global --unset https.proxy` and `git config --global --unset http.proxy` ?

Comment: the git config commands didn't help in this case. I edited my question and added all the git config values. I hope that helps

Comment: If you do the same git commands on your local machine, will it work as expected?

Comment: At the same time, you can also try to add the command: `git config http.timeout 600` and `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`  to expand the timeout limit and default buffer size

Comment: The `git config http.timeout 600` and `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` also didn't do it for me. I tried running the git command on both my work machine (though company VPN) and my personal one - it works as expected, no issues there

Comment: Can you check if there are any restriction in **Bitbucket -> Workspace settings ->Access controls**?

Comment: Both the Two-step verification and Ip Allowlisting are disabled. Everything seems to be default there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make this work with Bash script but I was able to **resolve** it by switching to PowerShell and executing exactly the same git commands.